# Core Data does not appear to save data

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

I want to save some things on a private context so that my UI isn't blocked. So I thought everything worked but when I disconnect myself from the wifi and restart the app, it doesn't show anything from coredata. So it seems to me that it doesn't save anything and I don't find out why.

This is my core data setup:

```
class CoreDataDatabaseService: NSObject {
    // Singleton
    static let sharedInstance = CoreDataDatabaseService()

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
        // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "be.donpironet.Gins4u" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
        let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
        return urls[urls.count-1]
    }()

    lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
        // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Model", withExtension: "momd")!
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
    }()

    lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
        // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
        // Create the coordinator and store
        let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
        let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Model.sqlite")
        var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
        do {
            try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
        } catch {
            // Report any error we got.
            var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
            dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
            dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

            dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
            let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "G_COREDATA", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
            // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            DDLogError("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }

        return coordinator
    }()

    lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator

        return managedObjectContext
    }()

    func privateContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        let managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
        managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.mainContext

        return managedObjectContext
    }
}
```

Like you can see my privateContext always has the mainContext as parent. I only save things on my private context and my main context is only showing data.

```
let managedContext = CoreDataDatabaseService.sharedInstance.privateContext()

... I create some objects

    do {
                    if managedContext.hasChanges {
                        try managedContext.save()
                        observer.on(.Next("Success"))
                        observer.on(.Completed)
                    }

                } catch let error as NSError  {
                    DDLogError("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
                    observer.on(.Error(error))
                }
```

When I run this when I have wifi the app shows me the result so the NSFetchResultController is triggered so I guess the models are in the database otherwise this couldn't be possible (I think).

So anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Why is the app not saving the result ( nevertheless the save action doesn't throw a error )

Comment: I implemented everything so that tutorial isn't helpful. It is saving because otherwise the NSFetchResultController would not trigger and display data. It's just that it is not showing when I'm offline.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When you save the child context you also need to save the parent context.

So after saving the private context just call save() on the maincontext and everything works.